Example program which uses QClipPlane from Qt3D
I'm looking for some example code of how to use QClipPlane, which is part of the Qt3D framework: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3drender-qclipplane.html.
I can take the "basicshapes-cpp" demo program provided by Qt, compile and run this successfully, which then draws the shapes in a window on screen for me.
I'd then like to add a clipping plane into this program. I assume QClipPlane is the candidate for this task, but I cannot understand how to incorporate this into a working example.
The furthest I have got is taking some of the example code from QRenderStateSet https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3drender-qrenderstateset.html, and replacing the QCullFace with QClipPlane instead.
Unfortunately, this only renders a totally blank window on screen. I then tried to add the renderSettings object from the above example directly to the torus entity, or the sphere entity from the basicshapes-cpp demo program. This resulted in the same effect.
I can't understand how QClipPlane is meant to be added to the demo program - is it through Qt3DWindow, QEntity (i.e. the root entity), the frame graph, or something else entirely? A working, demo program would be ideal. Thanks

This is probably overkill but I wrote a QML/Qt3D application called qml3DWater some time ago that renders a small lake using clipping planes to create the reflection and refraction effects. You can find more information about the use of clipping planes for this purpose here:

OpenGL Water Tutorials by ThinMatrix

Basically, clipping planes are defined as part of this custom PhongShadingMaterial so that objects that use this material can be rendered using a two render-pass approach:

on the first pass, a clipping plane vector allows us to render the bottom part of the mesh;
on the second pass, another clipping plane vector allows us to render the top part of the mesh;

The vertex shader for this PhongShadingMaterial uses the clipping plane vector to calculate the gl_ClipDistance[0] for each vertex of the mesh, essentially informing the vertex shader when a vertex needs to be discarded.
The frameGraph that defines the multiple render-pass approach can be found in main.qml.
WaterMaterial.qml also offers some additional documentation that explains how clipping planes are used to render the water reflection/refraction effects:

Enabling clipping planes on the frameGraph is essential to be able to set gl_ClipDistance[0] and have OpenGL use it for vertex culling.
This tells us how far a vertex is from the clipping plane 0. OpenGL only cares about the signed distance
of each vertex from that plane wherever that plane may be:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0NH9k4zTAqk&list=PLRIWtICgwaX23jiqVByUs0bqhnalNTNZh&index=3
Imagine a clipping plane separating whats below water and whats above water level:

The distance is positive when the vertex is inside of the plane (below water level);
The distance is negative when the vertex is outside the plane (above water level, the culling side of the plane);

Since this is done for every vertex, and OpenGL interpolates these distances to the whole Geometry
and any part of the geometry with a negative distnace is culled and therefore its not rendered, while
anything with a distance of 0.0 or bigger than 0.0 is rendered.


This doesn't really answer the question, but maybe it will help you somehow. I found an example on Qt Quick 3D with which you can cut the model along the x, y, z axes (https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquick3d-volumeraycaster-example.html). Here is the link to the sources https://invent.kde.org/qt/qt/qtquick3d/-/tree/dev/examples/quick3d/volumeraycaster.
https://i.sstatic.net/LhrHw9Jd.jpg
https://i.sstatic.net/3GSIpatl.jpg
